# 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

am new to mails in rails.I am referring http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html to learn. I am getting error like:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {

                :address        => "smtp.gmail.com",
                :port           => 587,
                :authentication => :plain,
                :user_name      => "<my gmail>@gmail.com",
                :password       => "<my gmail password>",
                :openssl_verify_mode  => 'none' }
```

I am try all answer but not resolved this problem.

Comment: what did you do to trigger error? also, post full backtrace errors. But it sounds like you need to read carefully instructions at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail  Gmail has more strict policy now.

Comment: also trying to bypass ssl is a good way to get you gmail hacked, not recommended.

Comment: this is error. Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
):

Comment: then go learn more at wherever it said to. But also did you read instructions specifically regarding gmail??

Comment: config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
 ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :user_name => '<my gmail>@gmail.com',
    :password => '<my gmail password>',
    :domain => 'gmail.com',
    :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :port => 587,
    :authentication => :plain 
  } user this my another project it is work fine but in this project got error?

Comment: I am already ON the less secure apps option in sender email.but still not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with this for hours... The fix was finally quite easy, you just have to allow google to use less secure apps: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1